# The method 'toImage' isn't defined for the type 'RenderObject'

Tags: flutter, dart, rendering

How to fix this error message:

> The method 'toImage' isn't defined for the type 'RenderObject'. Try
> correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a
> method named 'toImage'.

[image]

**My Code:**

```
  Future<void> saveImage() async {
    RenderObject? boundary = globalKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage();
    ByteData? byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    Uint8List pngBytes = byteData!.buffer.asUint8List();

    //Request permissions if not already granted
    if (!(await Permission.storage.status.isGranted))
      await Permission.storage.request();

    final result = await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(
        Uint8List.fromList(pngBytes),
        quality: 60,
        name: "logo_image");
    print(result);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to wrap the widget you want to convert to image into `RepaintBoundary` widget with `globalKey`.

Once that is done, you can change

```
RenderObject? boundary = globalKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
```

to

```
RenderRepaintBoundary? boundary = globalKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderRepaintBoundary?;
if (boundary == null) {
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because the **[RenderObject](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderObject-class.html)** class (or even **[RenderBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderBox-class.html)**) do not define `toImage` method. Instead you will have to cast to [**RenderRepaintBoundary**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderRepaintBoundary-class.html).

---

You are writing

```dart
RenderObject? boundary = globalKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage();
```

but in the [docu](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderRepaintBoundary/toImage.html) they write

```dart
final RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = globalKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject()! as RenderRepaintBoundary;
final ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage();
```

try correcting that...